# "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because..." ISSUE

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I spent several minutes to prepare sew screenshots and describe my problem - and finally I got this error:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't
>   allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.
>   sorry, the 'ubuntu' tag is not allowed. users with less than 300
>   reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'ubuntu' is new. Try using
>   an existing tag

Could you show this message on the beginning to prevent wasting time.

Comment: Note also, your time wasn't wasted! If you just remove the image and the ubuntu tag (the ubuntu tag is not needed anyway, since this site is only about ubuntu), your question should go through the filter.

Answer (score 7):

You can just post links to the images and a higher reputation-ed users will convert them in to images.

Comment: I know - but what happen if URL with my images disappear and/or I do not know how to do that and/or I do not want to do that?

Comment: I tried to use ubuntuone for share images and I got:


'Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.'

Comment: Just place the links, not the images with the image tag. It's the tag that's preventing you - not the actual use of images. Place those links in the bottom and someone will edit them in.

Comment: I cannot use also pure URLs :(
give up...

Comment: Gain more rep, edit your post :)

Comment: @thm I've seen people do hxxp://blahblah and then someone goes in and edits it. try that.